# Error when inserting strings with $( with Invoke-SqlCmd in Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTest (TestCol1 nchar(5))
```

Test:

Following work:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database "databasename" -ServerInstance "hostname" -OutputSqlErrors $True -Query "INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ('`$5')"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database "databasename" -ServerInstance "hostname" -OutputSqlErrors $True -Query "INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ('(5')"
```

Following fails with the error below:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database "databasename" -ServerInstance "hostname" -OutputSqlErrors $True -Query "INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ('`$(5')"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database "databasename" -ServerInstance "hostname" -OutputSqlErrors $True -Query "INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ('`$`(5')"
```

*Error:
Invoke-Sqlcmd :
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database "databasename" -ServerInstance "hostname" -Ou ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand*

Aftersome research I found that $( provides functionality in powershell thus is reserved.  However I tried escaping the parenthesis but with no success.  I've tried finding alternatative.  Any ideas on how I can do this?  If I use the CHAR function in SQL Server that works but it would be a pain to deal with in my code.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue seems that the $( is a reserved word in Powershell thus to make this work I had use the CHAR function to store the $ (CHAR(36)).  Once I did this it worked but for this project I abandoned using the Invoke-SqlCmd command and used a standard ADO.NET method.  It seems that the Invoke-SqlCmd wants to parse the command and for the reserved combination continues to see the reserved word even if you escape the characters.

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is disable the variables lookup in the invoke-Sqlcmd by adding **-DisableVariables**. 
`$()` is use to pass in variable into the sql statements.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $fileName -ServerInstance $serverInstance -DisableVariables
```

Source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
'INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ("$(5")'
```

or this:

```
'INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES (''$(5'')'
```

Comment: To provide a reason why this works: In PowerShell, double-quoted strings (`"hello"`) are parsed for variables.  Single-quoted strings (`'hello'`) are treated as literal strings and are never parsed.  Try the following: `$x = 0; "$x"; '$x'`.  That said, your first example `"INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ('\`$(5')"` should be working.  That is a correct string.

Comment: @BaconBits I think this comment was better in the OP, not in my answer. Or is for me this comment? :)

Comment: If I run it this way it is expecting more characters with the >> prompt.

Comment: @C.B. No, not really for you.  It just isn't obvious why a single quote would work but a double wouldn't.  I was expanding on your answer.  The verbiage is a bit weird though.  It should say "That said, the first example... ".  :)

Comment: @Russ960 What are your database and server names?  Do they have any reserved Powershell characters in them?

Comment: I don't want to give that out but no they don't.  However I have determine that the only rows that fail to insert include $(.  The ones with just ( or just $ succeed but the ones having $( fail with the parser error.  If I execute the insert in SSMS no problem inserts.  It is the powershell parser that is the problem.

Comment: @Russ960 Try assigning the string to a variable, and then passing the variable to the `-Query` parameter.

Comment: Yeah the original is that way but in troubleshooting I converted it over same issue.

Comment: @Russ960 I'm pretty sure that you found a bug!

Answer (score 0):

The $(anyvalue) are reserved variables to be used with SQLCMD.EXE
Change the symbol $ by the sql server CHAR(36):

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database "databasename" -ServerInstance "hostname" -OutputSqlErrors $True -Query "INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES (CHAR(36)+'(5)')"

Comment: That is what I determined and posted here previously.

Answer (score -2):

```
"INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ('`$5')"
```

Outputs a string

```
INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ('$5')
```

---

```
"INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ('(5')"
```

Outputs a string

```
INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ('(5')
```

---

```
"INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ('`$(5')"
```

Outputs a string

```
INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ('$(5')
```

---

```
"INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ('`$`(5')"
```

Outputs a string

```
INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ('$(5')
```

What do you want to insert? Actually '$5' or the value of the variable $5? Also, you have strange parentheses around your variable $5. Not sure if is suppose to be like that or your don't understand another important part of powershell variables? Because this a variable in a string `"There are $((Get-Process).Count) processes running"` too.

Comment: I am trying to insert $(5.  Don't ask me why I'm moving data from one system to another.

Comment: `'INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES ("$(5")'` or `"INSERT INTO MyTest VALUES (<backtick>"<backtick>$(5)<backtick>")"`. Hope I helped and not confused.